# How to add "Send Parameters With the Request" using java in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter and i want to execute jmeter in non-gui fashion using java code.

When testing on the endpoints i would like to pass the "Send Parameters with the Request" via java code. So i have tried sending the data as follows

```
        HTTPSampler httpSampler = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSampler.setProtocol("http");
        httpSampler.setDomain(hostip);
        httpSampler.setPort(8080);
        httpSampler.setPath(endpointpath);
        httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
        HTTPArgument httpArgument = new HTTPArgument();
        httpArgument.setValue("[{ \"firstname\": "", \"name\": \"Venkat\"}]");
```

No Error came. The request was not added to the DB

Can some one suggest and provide a sample code to add the post request body using java?

Comment: Kindly Refer : 1 - [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) 2 - [Regular_Expression_Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: Does it work fine in GUI mode first?

Comment: Yes it works fine in GUI MODE

Comment: Can you provide the complete code if possible? Also try to escape all "".

Comment: I have shared my code here "http://pastebin.com/yTvJBKkX"

Comment: it says paste has been removed.

Comment: @NachiketKate, just remove " in the URL

Comment: If I understand your need correctly, I think you can do it using properties in JMeter. Accept properties from user and then read and use properties in your code. Please correct If I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I have added the code again please refer link "http://pastebin.com/w3wdnJF3"

Answer (score 0):

httpSampler has no arguments associated. Basically you are just sending a http request without any argument.

You might have to use addTestElement / setArgument method to associate the parameters to the httpsampler.

```
            httpSampler.setMethod("POST");
            HTTPArgument httpArgument = new HTTPArgument();
            httpArgument.setValue("[{ \"firstname\": \"venkatachalam\", \"name\": \"Venkata\"}]");
            httpSampler.addTestElement(httpArgument);
```

Just curious - why are you creating your JMeter test using java by the way?

---

To run your JMeter test in non gui mode, use below command & options. (assuming you have %JMETER_HOME%/bin is added to your PATH variable)

```
jmeter -n -t D:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl
```

- -n [This specifies JMeter is to run in non-gui mode]
- -t  [name of JMX file that contains the Test Plan]
- -l  [name of JTL file to log sample results to]
- -j  [name of JMeter run log file].

Besides these options, JMeter has several other parameters that can be used for running in non-GUI mode.

- -R [list of remote servers] Run the test in the specified remote servers
- -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
  -P [proxy server port]

Comment: I have added the "httpSampler.addTestElement(httpArgument); and Arguments httpArgument = new Arguments();
httpArgument.addArgument("Test", "[{ "FirstName": "Venkatachalam", "name": "Venkata"}]");
httpSampler.setArguments(httpArgument);  still the post call does not work. To answer your question. Since i have worked on other testing tools i know java. Please let me know which will be suitable one to create jmeter test.

Comment: You can create jmeter programatically with java. But in my opinion it is very difficult to maintain & debug etc. Create a test & run in GUI mode to ensure that everything is correct. If everything is fine, then use the commands to run the same test file in the non gui mode.  check this link.  http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode